# Can't start program via SSH in windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh

I enabled the latest openSSH on Windows 10. Successfully login using a key (since the use doesn't have any password/blank password). However the command to start a program:

```
start notepad.exe
```

or

```
start "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"
```

doesn't actually launch the program (nothing happens) when I SSH from a linux system.

However, if I ran it from the CMD from the Windows itself (logged in using SSH, `ssh user@192.123.0.123 -i "key"`), it ran. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: is openSSH running as a service on the windows device? if so, try `runas /user:youruser "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"` if that works, I will explain.

Comment: Programs started as the non logged on user are invisible.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard it looks like it'll work, however since the user doesn't have any password (that's why SSH is using a key instead), I get error saying `RUNAS ERROR: unable to run - C:\Windows\notepad.exe" 1327: Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.` Is there a way to use a key file instead?

Comment: ok, so are you planning to actually open notepad.exe? or do you want to launch something specific, like scripts to do some automation etc? Please update your question with what you plan on doing, then I can give you some ideas.

Comment: I actually trying to run a installed program on `"C:\Program Files\MyProgram\Program.exe"`, but for example purposed let's use `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"` as substitute.

Comment: ok, but there are 2 scenarios.. 7zfm to do some automated zip process, which will store or extract files. Or just launching it so you can see it, I am expecting the first?

Comment: here is a scenario.. try this. `cmd /c echo Hello World > C:\Temp\Helloworld.txt` which will run, but not seen and store the actual data in the file.

Comment: At the moment I am only trying to launch the program only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178000/discussion-between-gerhard-barnard-and-gregor-isack).

Comment: Make it `/k` and read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start OpenSSH on Windows 10 (and set to start automatically when Windows boots up) using the Services admin tool.

Firstly though, i added OpenSSH Client and OpenSSH Server through Manage optional features (search optional features using Windows Search Bar) - see [Installation of OpenSSH For Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).

After OpenSSH was installed i started it. You can get to it easily by typing "services" into the Windows Search Bar, scroll down and find "OpenSSH SSH Server", right click and click "Start".

You can also set the service to start automatically by right clicking, select Properties and set Startup type "Automatic".

Comment: This does not answer the question. Neither the current question nor the current edit are asking how to get OpenSSH to start - we know they already got SSH server to start on Windows because they said they're able to SSH into Windows successfully. They are asking why certain commands aren't working as expected when executed over SSH.